# SSAS Offload Tabular Cube From Memory

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am looking for option to offload the Tabular cube from memory to tune the performance. Below is my use case.

Version: SSAS 2019

We have 4 Tabular cubes spread across 3 SSAS hosts. Each cube will be built in different schedule choose round robin to build the next cube.
Ex: cube1 is active in Host1 to users which was built on DAY1,
DAY2 - cube1 will be built in Host2 background and flip to users upon completion.
DAY3 - follows the same pattern

same case applies to cube2, 3 and 4(all 4 don't end up in same host, they follow random pattern because build schedule is different)

On Day3 - cube1 from Host3 is users facing, rest of the instances (cube1 in Host1 and Host2) are serving as backup incase if any data issues in host3 instance , we will flip the previous day version(Host2) to users. Since cube1 in Host1 and Host2 are failover versions(not an often case), don't want to keep the cube1 in memory on Host1 and Host2.

1. I want to offload non user facing cubes from memory, so that other cubes active in the host will get room.
2. Assuming this helps in performance as well, as our hosts close to memory threshold

As per my browse in internet, looks there is no straight forward way to achieve this by running any process options. Please suggest any workarounds or let me know if any of explanation is not clear, happy to update/clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Evicting the cube will not help performance.  It will have to be re-loaded to be used for failover, and if you don't have enough memory that will fail.  So you can't really use the memory you free by evicting it.

But the operation you're looking for is [SSAS Attach/Detatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/attach-and-detach-analysis-services-databases?view=asallproducts-allversions).  There's no way to keep the database attached but evict it from memory, but reloading it would be the same as an Attach.

SSMS knows how to do this and can generate the scripts for you.  To detach a tabular database use the TMSL command

```
{
  "detach": {
    "database": "AdventureWorksDW"
  }
}
```

to attach it again, discover the folder name in the filesystem, and run the XMLA command

```
<Attach xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Folder>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS16.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\AdventureWorksDW.2.db</Folder>
  <ReadWriteMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100">ReadWrite</ReadWriteMode>
</Attach>
```

Note that Attach is an expensive operation, as many of the in-memory data structures need to be rebuilt, as only the raw data is stored in the files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and sorry to come back on this late. Follow up question

Comment: Agree I should reserve the space in memory for failover. Follow up questions, 1. Detaching the tabular cube from memory would it improve the query performance of other cubes exists in the instance? 2. Anyway to keep only one copy at disk(house keeping purpose) which was detached recent and it helps to get the file name for attach programmatically during failover.